# Help identifying IC in switching power supply

Tags: pcb, amplifier, integrated-circuit, repair

I'm trying to repair an amplifier with a fault in the switching power supply, but can't for the life of me identify an IC that I need to replace. The number printed on the IC is LTBRZ 0D60 e3. I can't make out any obvious manufacturer logo, but the photo below may help:
[image: Unknown integrated circuit]

A little background info; the amp is a 16 channel Control4 amplifier from a home automation system. The incoming mains is taken down to +/- 48VDC by a separate power supply board, and that part seems to be working fine. However, there is no life in the main amp PCB and the LCD on the front of the unit does not come on. There are 12V and 6.25V test points nearby just out of shot on the photo, and neither have any voltage on them. From the state of the board, I suspect there has been water spilled on the PCB. The only other components on this section of the board are switching devices and those check out fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some variants of the [LTC3824](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3824fh.pdf) have an LTBRZ marking.

Comment: The R025 close to transistor and the application on p13 seem to confirm it.

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect such a fast response. Thank you both so much - there's no way that I would have ever tracked that down on my own. And, as you say, it matches the application notes and would make sense as it's being used in a buck application.